# Replication Documentation Suggestions

Tags: sql-server, documentation

I am looking for suggestions on the best way to document
replication....all publications....subscriptions....articles.

I currently have 2 data centers & 35 remote locations.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

This should be done on a database by database level.  The good news is I'd be suprised if your setup wasn't *server a* in site a replicates to *server b* at site B for most of your databases.  The reason for documenting it at the database level is in case you decide to consolidate SQL servers or migrate databases between servers.  You definitely want to include the following for each database:

Current publisher instance

Current distributor instance

Current remoste distributors (if any)

Current subscriber push instances

current subscriber pull instances

Publication list, if applicable (if entire database simply state that here)

Article list (if entire database state that here)

finally include a brief description as to what function this subscription supports.  This type of documentation setup is fine when you are replicating each database (or subset) as a publication.  If however you are publishing multiple database views/tables/SPs (etc) change this format around to be documented by publication instead (or at least in addition to)